# Possible to style other element on :focus?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

Is it possible to style another element  on :focus of a specific element?

Something like:

```
input:focus #header {
    display: none;
}
```

I tried doing that but it didn't work.

Comment: Well of course that's not going to work since `input` can never have descendants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,it is possible if element is a `sibling` or a `child` to the `:focus` element. If it is not your case (affect whatever you want) than you should use javascript.

Comment: Sibling or descendant, to be exact.

Answer (score 4):

```
.input:focus #header
```

That is applying selecting all `#header` where they are a descendant of `input`

If its a sibling so you want, use the next sibling selector `+`:

```
input:focus + #header
```

[For more information on child/sibling combinators](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use 'preceded by' selector -> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

HTML:

```
  <button>button</button>
  <div class="div1">div1</div>
```

CSS:

```
button:hover ~ .div1 {
    color: red; 
}
```

So you hover over the button BUT the  div1 element gets styled.

Just make sure that the BUTTON element is first and the element you are styling is SECOND.